# Creating JMeter scripts for ServiceNow applications

Tags: jmeter, servicenow

I am wondering if anyone was able to successfully create JMeter scripts for ServiceNow applications?
My challenge is that there are way too many recorded HTTP requests and JSONs in POST requests & response are huge and extremely hard to correlate dynamic values.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to [Web 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_2.0)

I'm afraid you will have to perform the correlation as the times where you could just replay the recorded test has gone.

If you're looking for a way of reducing effort required for the correlation implementation you can consider trying out an automated correlation solution like:

- [JMX Enhancer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jmx-enhancer-auto-correla/akoiagmmfbjephlbkncmnpdakfklipjd?hl=en)
- [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder with SmartJMX](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) export option

Otherwise you will have to [wait until it's implemented in JMeter](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/pull/499)